# Capturing arbitrary semantic URL arguments

Tags: page-template, advanced-custom-fields, routing

So,

My articles have this URL structure :

```
mydomain.com/category/article-name
```

I'm using ACF to add additional information to my post types. For example, another text field with some related information to my article. Let's call that field `tab-1`.

I don't wan't to show all this extra data immediately on the article page, but I want to have some sort of subpage on my article for that kind of extra data.

For example, this would be url of my sub page that will show only content from my article `tab-1` field:

```
mydomain.com/category/article-name/tab-1
```

Is something like this achievable in wordpress? Essentially, I'd just like to capture that extra URL part `/tab-1` in my template file and than base on it's actual value, show appropriate field on the article.

And all that without getting `404` error :D

Comment: Definitely achievable.  This tutorial walks you through the steps: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing in WP that hits a passable balance of such functionality to not so painful implementation is [rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

They are structured a little differently from your example (i.e. `/tab/2`) but they are *easy* to implement and order of magnitude less painful than dealing with Rewrite API usually is.

Comment: hm... well, my fields will be dynamically named, so I would have repeater field in ACF where I can add section named `Some statistics` with some `content` related to it and than url would be `/article-name/some-statistics/`. Am I right in assuming that I could do something like this with rewrite endpoint? : `/article-name/detalis/{capture-value}`

Comment: also, all tutorials that I've found are "handling" this new endpoint. I don't want to "handle/redirect" anything, I just want it to act the same way as with regular post, just with `$detalis` variable accessible.

Comment: Yes to first. And you can do whatever you want with query variable which endpoint will capture for you. Redirect is merely one of possible use cases.